# Image by a translate/homeomorphism of a set E of Lebesgue measure 0 is disjoint with E

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

This is a question on Walter Rudin's RCA (exercise 5.21):

> Suppose $E\subset\mathbb{R}$ is a measurable set with $m(E)=0$. Must there be a translate $E+x$ of $E$ that does not intersect $E$? Must there be a homeomorphism $h:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ such that $h(E)$ does not intersect $E$?

I am guessing the answer to the first one is no, because it being true would immediately answer the second one ($t\mapsto t+x$ would be a valid homeomorphism). However I can't even start to prove neither of the questions.

PS: this was asked before I know, but an example of $E$ for which a translate doesn't exist wasn't given, and also the existence of $h$ was proven using a little bit of category theory which I know nothing about.

Comment: Enumerate the rational numbers $x_n$, for $n=0,1,2,...$. Cover the $n$-th rational number with an open interval centered at it with radius $2^{-n}/m$. The union $A_m$ of those intervals is dense and has measure $1/m$. Then $E=\bigcap_{m=1}^{\infty}A_m$ has measure zero. If $h:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ is a homeomorphism, then $h(E)=\bigcup_{m=1}^{\infty}h(A_m)$ is also a countable intersection of open dense sets. Therefore $E\cap h(E)$ is a countable intersection of open dense sets. By [Baire category theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baire_category_theorem) $E\cap h(E)$ is dense.

Comment: In particular for $h(t)=t+x$ one also has $E\cap h(E)$ is dense.

Comment: By the way, [Category theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category_theory) is used to name of something else, that hardly proves anything on its own.

Comment: The $\bigcup$ in the first comment should be a $\bigcap$.

Answer (score 4):

The answer to both questions is **no**.

1. For an explicit counterexample consider the Cantor set $C \subseteq [0,1]$ and set
   $$E := \bigcup_{k\in\mathbb{Z}}(E+k).$$ Clearly $E$ is a measurable set with $m(E) = 0$. We'll show that every translate of $E$ intersects $E$.

   Indeed, for $x \in \mathbb{R}$ we have $y \in E \cap (E+x)$ if and only if $y = e = e'+x$ for some $e,e' \in E$. Equivalently, $x =e' - e$ for some $e,e' \in E$. [Recall](https://www.cut-the-knot.org/do_you_know/cantor3.shtml) that $C-C =[-1,1]$ so
   $$E-E \supseteq (C+k)-C = [k-1,k+1], \quad\text{for all } k \in \mathbb{Z}$$
   and therefore $E-E = \mathbb{R}$. We conclude that every $x \in \mathbb{R}$ can be written as a difference of two elements of $E$ and hence $E \cap (E+x)$ is nonempty.
2. For the second question, let $E$ be a dense set of measure zero which can be written as a countable intersection $E = \bigcap_{n=1}^\infty U_n$ of open sets $U_n$. For an explicit example we can take
   $$U_n = \bigcup_{k=1}^\infty\left\langle q_k-\frac1{n2^k}, q_k+\frac1{n2^k}\right\rangle$$
   where $(q_k)_k$ are the rational numbers. We'll show that for every homeomorphism $h : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ holds that $h(E) \cap E$ is nonempty. We have
   $$h(E) \cap E = h\left(\bigcap_{m=1}^\infty U_m\right) \cap \left(\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty U_n\right) = \left(\bigcap_{m=1}^\infty h(U_m)\right) \cap \left(\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty U_n\right) = \bigcap_{m,n \in \mathbb{N}} h(U_m) \cap U_n.$$  Since $h$ is a homeomorphism, the sets $h(U_m) \cap U_n$ are also open dense sets in $\mathbb{R}$ so by the Baire Category Therorem, the countable intersection $\bigcap_{m,n \in \mathbb{N}} h(U_m) \cap U_n$ is nonepmty. Therefore $h(E) \cap E \ne \emptyset$. 
   Obviously every translate of $E$ intersects $E$ as well.

Comment: Really clear answer, thanks!

Comment: That's just $$\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty h(U_n) \cap U_n$$ at the end. There is no need to introduce another variable, $m$.